# How do I change an AC outlet into a switched outlet using wireless technology?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, home-automation

I have an outlet that's live, and I want to make it switched without having to get an electrician. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presto!   (Emeril would say - BAM!)

Heath/Zenith BL-6136-WH Wireless Switch Outlet, White

[http://www.amazon.com/Heath-Zenith-BL-6136-WH-Wireless-Switch/dp/product-description/B000OUW7MA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OUW7MA)

[image]

P.S. Did you try googling for it yourself first?  Just sayin'...

Comment: Thanks! (And yes, but I think I might not've known enough to get very far. I ended up looking at a number of x10 options but couldn't find the right one. This looks simpler than everything else I found. Much obliged.)

Answer (score 2):

Woodworkers often want to be able to control a dust collector remotely, so they sell [remote controlled switches for that purpose](http://www.woodcraft.com/Product/2005117/8394/110V-Remote.aspx). I use one like this, and it works exactly as advertised.

[image: dust collector switch]